# How to add i18n feature with mako template engine?

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, mako, python-babel

I am doing a sample to test that.

myprj/setup.py

```
requires = [
    'pyramid',
    'pyramid_mako == 1.0.2',
    'mako',
    'Babel',
    'lingua',
]

setup(name='myprj',
    ...
    messages_extractors = { '.': [
        ('**.py', 'lingua_python', None ),
        ('templates/**.html', 'mako', None ),
        ('templates/**.mako', 'mako', None ),
        ('static/**', 'ignore', None ),
    ]},
)
```

myprj/setup.cfg

```
[compile_catalog]
directory = myprj/locale
domain = myprj
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
add_comments = TRANSLATORS:
output_file = myprj/locale/myprj.pot
width = 80

[init_catalog]
domain = myprj
input_file = myprj/locale/myprj.pot
output_dir = myprj/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = myprj
input_file = myprj/locale/myprj.pot
output_dir = myprj/locale
previous = true
```

myprj/babel.cfg

```
[python: myprj/**.py]

[mako: myprj/templates/**.html]
input_encoding = utf-8
```

`myprj/myprj/__init__.py`

```
def main(...):
    ...
    config.add_translation_dirs('myprj.locale')
```

myprj/views.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.html')
def my_view(request):
    return {'project': 'myprj'}
```

myprj/myprj/templates/mytemplate.html

```
<body>
    ${_('search_documentation')}
</body>
```

myprj/myprj/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/myprj.po

```
msgid "search_documentation"
msgstr "Search Documentation"
```

After I compiled the .po file to .mo file and run the project. It shows

```
pyramid_mako.MakoRenderingException

MakoRenderingException: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myprj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_mako-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid_mako/__init__.py", line 148, in __call__
    result = template.render_unicode(**system)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myprj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 454, in render_unicode
    as_unicode=True)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myprj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 829, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myprj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 864, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myprj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 890, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/test/myprj/myprj/templates/mytemplate.html", line 5, in render_body
    ${_('search_documentation')}
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

I have read the mako's document about babel:

> http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#babel

But I don't know how to use it. I wrote the `msgstr` in the .po file. Didn't it find that path?

## Tree

```
(myprj)➜  myprj  tree
.
...
├── babel.cfg
├── development.ini
├── production.ini
├── myprj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── locale
│   │   ├── en
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── myprj.mo
│   │   │       └── myprj.po
│   │   ├── myprj.pot
...
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── mytemplate.html
...
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```